# Create Custom Dialog in an Adapter

Tags: java, xml, firebase, android-studio

I'm trying to display a Custom Dialog tapping a Card (I use recyclerview and firebase). I have an Adapter in which I have the onClick method. In there I want to put my custom dialog in order to open it when I click the card.

Here is the ArticoloAdapter.java

```
public class ArticoloAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticoloAdapter.VersionVH> {

    private List<Articolo> listaArticoli;
    private Context mCtx;

    public ArticoloAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Articolo> listaArticoli){
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.listaArticoli = listaArticoli;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ArticoloAdapter.VersionVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.articolo_stock, parent, false);
        return new VersionVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ArticoloAdapter.VersionVH holder, int position) {
        final Articolo articolo = listaArticoli.get(position);
        holder.nome.setText(articolo.getNome());

        if(articolo.getQuantita() == 1){
            String quantita = Integer.toString(articolo.getQuantita()) + " Disponibile";
            holder.quantita.setText(quantita);
        } else {
            String quantita = Integer.toString(articolo.getQuantita()) + " Disponibili";
            holder.quantita.setText(quantita);
        }
        Picasso.get().load(articolo.getImg()).into(holder.img);
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
        return listaArticoli.size();
    }

    public class VersionVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CardView cardView;
        private ImageView img;
        private TextView nome, quantita;

        public VersionVH(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            nome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomeArticolo);
            quantita = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantita);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.immagine);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);

            cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //here i want to put my custom_dialog
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my StockFragment (in which I have my card retrieved from Firebase):

```
public class StockFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Articolo> listaArticoli;
    private ArticoloAdapter articoloAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference query;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stock, container, false);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewStock);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(articoloAdapter);
        listaArticoli = new ArrayList<>();

        query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Articoli");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

        return root;
    }

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listaArticoli.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Articolo articolo = snapshot.getValue(Articolo.class);
                listaArticoli.add(articolo);
            }
            articoloAdapter = new ArticoloAdapter(getActivity(), listaArticoli);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(articoloAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
    };
}
```

and here is my custom_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="650dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
    tools:ignore="UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialXml">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06999999"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="146dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="146dp"
        android:text="Nome Prodotto"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19999999">

    </TextView>

    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/materialTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="Ciao questo è un testo di prova per daniele e vedere se gli piace o meno come esce"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3">

    </com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:hint="Nome"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textNome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:hint="Cognome"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textCognome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:hint="Numero Di Telefono"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/textNumero"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/testEnabeld"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Prova"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/switchGaranzia"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchGaranzia"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Garanzia"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />




    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="328dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.925">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8_utente_24" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icons8_utente_24" />


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below and add a child with match_parent attribute width and height inside the CardView and add the listener to the child view instead of the CardVeiw

```
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //here i want to put my custom_dialog
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewPager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewPager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
    });
```